# Changing the mouse pointer in JtextPane

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtextpane

I have a `JTextPane` which has the content type **text/plain**. I set some texts to that `JTextPane` and it contain some texts which display `URLs`. I want to change the mouse pointer when I point the mouse to that text only into the hand pointer. 
Is this function achievable? 
Note: I have the content of the `JTextPane` as `text/plain`. It cannot be changed to `text/html`

thanx

Answer (score 5):

You could try this:

```
pane.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

Where `pane` is your `JTextPane`.

Comment: `pane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));` should be better.

Comment: @FredericLeitenberger Why is `Cursor.getPredefinedCursor` better? The constructor and this `static` method do the same thing.

Comment: Because it is cached (faster) - more relevant if called very often.

Answer (score 4):

Did you read my answer in your posting on [Adding tooltips to JTextPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561506/adding-tooltips-to-jtextpane)?

Well the concept is the same. You use a MouseListener and convert the mouse point to get the text at the caret position. When you are over a url text then you change the cursor.

The Utilities class might help you access the text at the caret location.

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that shows what you have tried and shows what problems you are having.