# How do I use Windows' "disabled" cursor in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In the software I am currently developing, I want to disable a GUI element, bot not only want to grey it out, but signal it with the *[disabled](https://imgur.com/a/ZaPYN)* cursor from Windows. I know the other option of making your own picture, but it comes with some [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326256/implementing-cursor-in-java-with-some-transparency). Other Desktop Envoirements do have simmalar Icons, at least I could find some in Icon Packs for Mac, KDE, Unity and Gnome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the mouse pointer in JtextPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615940/changing-the-mouse-pointer-in-jtextpane)

Comment: The obvious answer would be to use a custom cursor without any partially transparent pixels! (A GIF is good for that, since it does not support partial transparency.)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle no it isn't, I forgot to mention, that there is no tag for "disabled"

Comment: So.. how'd you go using my suggestion?