# setting a tooltip at specified location (x,y) on a picture

Tags: java, tooltip

I want to set a tooltip at an specific location at my picture. and then once I do that I want to then if the user clicks the tooltip then a picture pops up basically. Here's my code. My question is how do I make a "invisible button" basically invisible box from point x to point y

```
//********************************************************************
//  TransitMap.java       Authors: Lewis/Loftus
//
//  Demonstrates the use a scroll 
//********************************************************************

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TransitMap
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Presents a frame containing a scroll pane used to view a large
   //  map of the New York transit system.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("New York Transit Map");

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("fortress.jpg");
      JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);

      JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(imageLabel);
      sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 400));

      frame.getContentPane().add(sp);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a tooltip at a specific location on a `JComponent` you need to override the [`JComponent.getToolTipText(MouseEvent)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getToolTipText-java.awt.event.MouseEvent-). This will get called if you register your `JComponent` to the `ToolTipManager` with [`ToolTipManager.registerComponent(JComponent)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html#registerComponent-javax.swing.JComponent-)

To make the tooltip clickable is a bigger problem, but I found an question here on SO that got an [accepted answer on how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6561804/2927457). Have not tested it myself though.